# Convert a String Containing an Array to an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have a string that contains an array that i would like to convert into an array. How would you do this?

I want to convert this:

```
myvar=
"[[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 23),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 24),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 25),3],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 26),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 27),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 28),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 29),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 30),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 31),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 01),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 02),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 03),1],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 04),2],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 05),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 06),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 07),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 08),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 09),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 10),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 11),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 12),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 13),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 14),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 15),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 16),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 17),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 18),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 19),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 20),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 21),0]]"
myvar.class
>>string
```

Into This:

```
myvar = 
[[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 23),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 24),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 25),3],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 26),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 27),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 28),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 29),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 30),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 31),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 01),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 02),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 03),1],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 04),2],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 05),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 06),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 07),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 08),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 09),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 10),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 11),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 12),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 13),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 14),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 15),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 16),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 17),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 18),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 19),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 20),0],[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 21),0]]
myvar.class
>>Array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the obvious answer involves `eval`, this is dangerous. I would instead recommend parsing it. Since this is quite a well defined data format (it seems), you can use this:

```
myvar.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).each_slice(4).map{|*x,y| [Date.UTC(*x), y]}
```

this will

- pull out all the digits
- convert them to integers
- separate them into groups of four
- apply the first three of each group to Date.UTC as the first through third arguments
- pair each date with its corresponding `y`
- create an array containing all of these pairs.

I don't have a `Date.UTC` method, but I assume you have some custom method called that.

Comment: Hmm...so Date.UTC is actually a javascript function that i'm trying to embed in the html, and not a function in Ruby. Your solution is technically correct, though provides an error because ruby has no date.utc. Oh well... thanks for the info, i'll likely use it later.

Answer (score 0):

try eval command

> x = eval("[\"foo\",\"bar\",\"land\"]")
>
> => ["foo", "bar", "land"]
>
> x
>
> => ["foo", "bar", "land"]

but eval is **danger** be care full when use it.